# Not able to add data label in waterfall chart using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot waterfall chart using ggplot2. When I am placing the data labels it is not putting in the right place.

Below is the code I am using

```
dataset <- data.frame(TotalHeadcount = c(-417, -12, 276, -276, 787, 14), Category =  LETTERS[1:6])
dataset$SortedCategory <- factor(dataset$`Category`, levels = dataset$`Category`)
dataset$id <- seq_along(dataset$TotalHeadcount)
dataset$type <- ifelse(dataset$TotalHeadcount > 0, "in",   "out")
dataset[dataset$SortedCategory %in% c("A", "F"), "type"] <- "net"
dataset$type <- factor(dataset$type, levels = c("out", "in", "net"))
dataset$end <- cumsum(dataset$`TotalHeadcount`)
dataset$end <- c(head(dataset$end, -1), 0)
dataset$start <- c(0, head(dataset$end, -1))
dataset$value <-dataset$`TotalHeadcount`
library(ggplot2)
strwr <- function(str) gsub(" ", "\n", str)
ggplot(dataset, aes(fill = type))+ geom_rect(aes(x = SortedCategory,  xmin = id - 0.45, xmax = id + 0.45, ymin = end,   ymax = start))+ scale_x_discrete("", breaks = levels(dataset$SortedCategory), labels = strwr(levels(dataset$SortedCategory)))+ theme_bw()+ theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "gray"))+guides(fill=FALSE)
```

And below is the output. I want the data label to be just at the beginning or at the end of the bar.
I am not very expert in R. Just trying to learn. Any help would be really appreciated.

I was following the below blog

https://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/05/10/ggplot2-waterfall-charts/

but somehow when I write the same code in geom_text it gives me an error. Could be a syntax related issue.

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example we can use? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you for quick response, I am using Power BI as a source of my dataset and it has my real time project data. The link I shared has a good example but somehow I am stuck at the last step of data label. Somehow I am not able to use geom_text with proper syntax.

Comment: Can you please make a reproducible example then? The point of it is to have a dataset that we can easily use to test your code and more easily find your error. Looking at your link, I still do not know how to make a dataset to test your code with.

Comment: Just added it. Not able to upload the Excel file. So pasted it as image. also added full code.

Comment: Can you download R on your computer and put the code into R? The premise behind reproducible example is that someone can copy and paste your data and code from your post into R and run it immediately. Even making a matrix to suit your Excel file, I cannot reproduce your data and code without getting error messages.

Comment: Just add `dput(dataset)` to the question (after all those lines of data manipulation), please.

Comment: I have updated the question with proper formatting and also added dataset which can be directly executed in R. I have removed the data label syntax as it was not working fine. Need your help to add data label on this code. Basically I would need conditional data label for each type.

Comment: never mind I was able to figure out the issue with my code. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach with ggplot.

First the data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(z = c(-417, -12, 276, -276, 787, 14),
                  b =  LETTERS[1:6])

library(tidyverse)
```

Calculate the `cumsum` and the `lag` of the `cumsum` for `geom_rect` coords

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(val = cumsum(z),
         lag = c(0, lag(val)[-1]),
         b1 = as.numeric(b)) -> df1

ggplot(df1)+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = b1 - 0.45,
                xmax = b1 + 0.45, ymin = lag, ymax = val)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = b1, y = val, label = val), #or `label = z`
            vjust = ifelse(df1$val < df1$lag, -0.2, 1)) + #geom_text vjust depends on the direction of the value
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:6, labels = df1$b)
```

[image]

an easier way, but I think the labels position can not be changed at this moment but it is planned:

> rect_text_labels_anchor    (character) How should rect_text_labels be
>   positioned? In future releases, we might have support for north or
>   south anchors, or for directed positioning (negative down, positive
>   up) etc. For now, only centre is supported.

```
library(waterfalls)


df1 <- data.frame(z = c(-417, -12, 276, -276, 787, 14),
                  b =  LETTERS[1:6])
```

[image]

you could also color it the same way in ggplot:

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(val = cumsum(z),
         lag = c(0, lag(val)[-1]),
         b1 = as.numeric(b),
         color = ifelse(val <lag, "down", "up")) -> df1

ggplot(df1)+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = b1 - 0.45,
                xmax = b1 + 0.45, ymin = lag, ymax = val, fill = color)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = b1, y = val, label = z),
            vjust = ifelse(df1$val < df1$lag, -0.2, 1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:6, labels = df1$b)
```

[image]

EDIT: answers to the questions in comments.

Filled waterfall:

```
df1 <- data.frame(z = c(-417, -12, 276, -276, 787, 14),
                  b =  LETTERS[1:6],
                  group = rep(c("AB", "CD", "EF"), each = 2))

df1 %>%
  mutate(val = cumsum(z),
         lag = c(0, lag(val)[-1]),
         b1 = as.numeric(b),
         g1 = as.numeric(group)) -> df1

ggplot(df1)+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = g1 - 0.45,
                xmax = g1 + 0.45, ymin = lag, ymax = val, fill = b)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = g1, y = val, label = z),
              vjust = ifelse(df1$val < df1$lag, -0.2, 1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:3, labels = unique(df1$group))
```

[image]

To answer what went wrong with your geom_text code I would need to see it. Other then that your code works, but it over-complicates things. I advise you to learn a bit of tidyverse functions, data manipulation will be much cleaner then.

One more note, adding back-ticks:

```
dataset$`TotalHeadcount`
```

is not necessary when your column names do not contain special characters:

```
dataset$TotalHeadcount
```

EDIT2: to change to order on the x axis you would first change the levels of the grouping factor and then do the calculation and plotting:

```
df1 <- data.frame(z = c(-417, -12, 276, -276, 787, 14),
                  b =  LETTERS[1:6],
                  group = rep(c("AB", "CD", "EF"), each = 2))

df1 %>%
  mutate(group = factor(group, levels = c("AB", "EF", "CD"))) %>%
  arrange(group) %>%
  mutate(val = cumsum(z),
         lag = c(0, lag(val)[-1]),
         b1 = as.numeric(b),
         g1 = as.numeric(group)) -> df1

ggplot(df1)+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = g1 - 0.45,
                xmax = g1 + 0.45, ymin = lag, ymax = val, fill = b)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = g1, y = val, label = z),
            vjust = ifelse(df1$val < df1$lag, -0.2, 1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:3, labels = unique(df1$group))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have edited the question with proper formatting and dataset as well.

Comment: I have tried your approach with sample dataset and it worked fine. But I also want to know what is wrong with my code. I mean something to do with syntax. If you can help me with that..

Comment: by any chance do you know how to create stacked waterfall chart using the same concept ?  Suppose A and B is grouped as AB, C and D as grouped as CD and similarly E and F as EF group. So X axis should have AD, CD, EF. 
And AD as a bar should have -417 and -12 stacked

Comment: Added code for stacked waterfall. To explain what went wrong with your `geom_text` code you will need to post it.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. It was a great learning. If I want to show AB, EF and then CD in the X axis ? I mean Custom ordering of the x axis group...

Comment: @Akash no problem, added example

Comment: Thank you so much.